# How do I create an object name in R

Tags: r, object, names

I'd like to use the value of a variable as part of the name of an object to make the creation of new objects with names that I don't have to list out explicitly. An example:

Here is what I don't want to do, declare every single name for 10 objects going down the list from 1 to 10.

```
a=41:50

a1=a[1]
a2=a[2]
a3=a[3]
a4=a[4]
a5=a[5]
a6=a[6]....
```

Here is what would make more sense - just putting the name some how as "a" and then combined with the value of i in the loop. Does the same thing, creates 10 objects.

```
for(i in 1:10){
a#paste.in.the.value.of.i.somehow...=a[i]
}
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: There should be no need to do this at all. Creating a bunch of different variable names like that is almost always a mistake. You should keep them in some sort of collection, whether a vector or list. You can have named elements in either. They are just as easy, if not easier, to work with than having bunches of different variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 for(i in 1:10) {assign(paste0("a", i), a[i])}
 a1
 #[1] 41
 a2
 #[1] 42
 a3
 #[1] 43
```

Comment: This is a bad solution.